# PHP can’t load php_oci8_11g.dll and php_pdo_oci.dll

Tags: php, oracle11g

I’d used php-5.3.16-Win32-VC9-x86 and Oracle11gXE.

Yesterday I changed Oracle to its Standard Edition.

Since I changed Oracle product my application has stopped.

I saw these messages in apache’s log like bellow.

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'C:\PHP\PHP-5.3.16\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll'

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'C:\PHP\PHP-5.3.16\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll'

Dose any one know how to fix this problem?

Do I need Oracle Instant client?

Actually I didn’t care about Oracle Instant Client when I installed product.

I’ve checked environment variable and PATH is normal.

Path=C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\PHP\php-5.3.16;・・・・・

Comment: Not sure about Windows, but on Linux, the Oracle Instant Client needed to be present, and in the path.  I don't remember the details or what version this was though...

Comment: just copy the oci.dll into the windows/system32 folder